# Why do tags like <input> function as an HTML tag in the title of a question on Stack Overflow? Will this cause security issues?

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, security, ask-question-wizard-2018

My friend and I were writing a question title on this site, We wanted to use an HTML tag, but we saw to our surprise that the title of the question had interpreted our HTML Tag. I was wondering if this could be a security issue for Stack Overflow?

I have not made a bug report yet as I am not sure if this is done on purpose.

As attachment, you will see a screenshot of the following line used as title:

```
how do I use <iframe width="560" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" ?
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-
picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Possibly XSS? What if there were script tags? This needs to be fixed ASAP

Comment: I also screen recorded the moment I found the bug, but I know no simple way to share this video.

Comment: @Anton We had a question about that last year http://meta.stackoverfiow.com/questions/283762/how-to-share-videos-in-comments-or-posts

Comment: Sounds like you can only XSS yourself since it's while asking questions, but still...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's odd -- the Stack Overfiow page redirects to YouTube.

Comment: @JL2210 Look at the domain name carefully.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I know. Look at my comment carefully: Overf**i**ow

Comment: @weegee I suspect there's no exploitable XSS hole here because I think the missing escaping is only in the question wizard, which only ever shows your own content to you (thus only allowing the user to XSS themselves). So: sloppy, but not a security hole in itself. I'm more worried that the fact that this was able to slip through the net at all (along with a similar bug in the mod tools that Cody posted about a while back and then deleted that I think really was an XSS hole) is probably a giant flashing warning sign that there are other XSS holes lurking in the codebase.

Comment: @MarkAmery able to do self XSS is a big scaring point itself.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up! This is now fixed:

[image: an image of the wizard "similar questions" page showing no results found and the title properly escaped]

Comment: I think he deserves some swag! What a catch...

Comment: This is the second instance of missing HTML escaping here I've learned of in the last few months. (The previous one was an XSS hole Cody stumbled across in the mod tools, and posted about here without appreciating its significance.) Can I suggest that it'd be a really good idea for one of you to do an audit of your codebase for XSS holes? Even spending an hour or two just doing some regex searches of your codebase for spots where values get templated/formatted/concatenated into HTML and then skimming them by eye to see if the values are escaped would probably have caught these last two bugs.